# Wrong parsing command from date manpage?

Tags: terminal, command-line, time

In the Apple's *date* manpage (`$ man date`) it's written:

```
Finally the command:

     `date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s"

can be used to parse the output from date and express it in Epoch time.
```

But when I'm executing this command (`` $ date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s" ``) in a new Basic Shell from Terminal I get:

```
Failed conversion of ``Ven 12 mai 2017 08:22:03 CEST'' using format ``%a %b %d %T %Z %Y''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Why? Does it same for you? How can I correct it?

*NB: I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 with French settings and Paris local time (UTC +02:00)*

Comment: Seems to be a locale issue. What happens when you preference the command with `LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: @fd0 I think you can add this as an answer. I had the same output as OP, but after setting the `LC_ALL` it works as expected.

Comment: @fd0 After launching `LC_ALL=C` the `date` command works ! Seems to be an answer… In my case, to go back to the old setting: `LC_ALL=fr_FR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the following date format:

```
 %a %d  %b   %Y %H:%M:%S   %Z
Ven 12 mai 2017 08:22:03 CEST
```

So the correct command is

```
date -j -f "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z" "`date`" "+%s"
```

Comment: `%T` also works instead of `%H:%M:%S`

Comment: For me it's working :

`$ LC_ALL=fr_FR`

`$ date`
`Ven 12 mai 2017 11:50:00 CEST`

``$ date -j -f "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z" "`date`" "+%s"``
`1494582685`